# Simple heatmap with 2 1D columns as x and y-axis, and 1 1D column as z-axis

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, coordinates, heatmap

I have the dataframe with x- and y-axis coordinates and z-values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,2,3,3,3],'y':[1,1,2,1,2,3],'z':[3,2,4,5,1,6]})
df
```

How do I plot a correlation-like heatmap with only these values i.e. 3x3 matrix with only one triangle half filled.

Was thinking of using seaborn, but any solution would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pivot your table (I included the seaborn solution as you mentioned):

```
pivot = df.pivot(index='x', columns='y', values='z')
ax = sns.heatmap(pivot, annot=True)
plt.show()
```

output:

[image]

You can remove the annotation if you don't need it or swap `x` and `y` if you need to swap the axis, like this:

```
pivot = df.pivot(index='y', columns='x', values='z')
ax = sns.heatmap(pivot)
plt.show()
```

output:

[image]